# TransactionManagementError While Executing Unittest in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-testing

I have written a test which checks whether *IntegrityError* was raised in case of duplicate records in the database. To create that scenario I am issue a REST API twice. The code looks like this:

```
class TestPost(APITestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass()
        common.add_users()

    def tearDown(self):
        super().tearDown()
        self.client.logout()

    def test_duplicate_record(self):
        # first time
        response = self.client.post('/api/v1/trees/', dict(alias="some name", path="some path"))
        # same request second time
        response = self.client.post('/api/v1/trees/', dict(alias="some name", path="some path"))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_400_BAD_RREQUEST)
```

But I get an error stack like this

```
 "An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't "
django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError: An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block.
```

> How can I avoid this error this is certainly undesirable.

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `self.client.logout()` from the `tearDown` method. Django rolls back the transaction at the end of each test. You shouldn't have to log out manually.

Comment: wow ! the problem has resolved after removing the logout. Could you please help me understand, where "transaction" has come into picture at first place and why removing "logout" actually resolved it. I think test.APITestCase is doing much more than what I think.

Comment: An error occurred in one of your tests. You then called `self.client.logout()` in the teardown method. This isn't possible, because it's not possible to execute queries in the transaction after there has been an error.

Answer (score 3):

I've come across this issue today, and it took me a while to see the bigger picture, and fix it properly. It's true that removing `self.client.logout()` fixes the issue, and is probably not needed there, but the problem lies in your view.

Tests which are subclasses of `TestCase` wrap your test cases and tests in db transactions (atomic blocks), and your view somehow breaks that transaction. For me it was swallowing an `IntegrityError` exception. At that point, the transaction was already broken, but Django didn't know about it, so it couldn't correctly perform a rollback. Any query that would then be executed would cause a `TransactionManagementError`.

The fix for me was to correctly wrap the view code in yet another atomic block:

```
try:
    with transaction.atomic():  # savepoint which will be rolled back
        counter.save()  # the operation which is expected to throw an IntegrityError
except IntegrityError:
    pass  # swallow the exception without breaking the transaction
```

This may not be a problem for you in production, if you're not using `ATOMIC_REQUESTS`, but I still think it's the correct solution.

Comment: What is it about ATOMIC_REQUESTS that would make this problematic in production?

Comment: @AndrewKonoff `ATOMIC_REQUESTS` wrap the whole view in a transaction, which might be really useful when a crash occurs in the middle of the views' execution. But it then also creates the same scenario as in the tests.